# Magento: output an attibute as a link

Tags: magento, attributes, navigation, magento-1.4

I want to create a per-brand, per-author, per-manufacturer navigation in Magento.
So I'm trying to output an attribute as something like "mysite.com/attribute/brand/brand_name" and then I'll create a custom CMS page to display all products with this brand_name.
I know how to create the link, but I don't know where to put my code!
Which is the best way to get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution here:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/catalog/how_to_display_a_product_attribute_url_link_in_the_product_page

Hope it can be helpful for someone else.

Comment: The link is dead.